# Can you help me understand why this closed question is going to be deleted?

Tags: discussion

This Q (not mine) which was closed as too broad a long time back, has now attracted 6 delete votes:

[How to make a weird guy stop touching me?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/how-to-make-a-weird-guy-stop-touching-me)

According to the [help centre](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools),

> When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!

The question and many of its answers are highly upvoted. Also, it was asked at a time when IPS.SE was only in its second month and our criteria for judging the content and scope of posts were still evolving. I am not asking why it was closed as too broad: but can you help me understand why it needs to be deleted?

Specifically I would like to understand how an on-topic question (even if closed as too broad) and its highly acclaimed answers taken together are "of no lasting value whatsoever" and need to be hidden from most of the people reading or using this website.

Note:

1. I am aware the Q is now old enough that nobody will lose hard-earned reputation by its deletion, I think.
2. Anticipating a possible answer, may I suggest that "the question was not improved after being closed" appears an unconvincing reason for deletion in view of the highly upvoted Q and A, and doesn't automatically seem to meet the criteria for deletion set out in the help centre.
3. Also, at least 250 questions [remain closed](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?page=6&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=closed%3a1) on IPS going back to late June 2017. Are we going to delete them all? Or is there something especially delete-worthy about this particular question?

Although I have already accepted @Tinkeringbell's prompt and convincing answer, members are most welcome to contribute your valuable inputs in answers and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.

**There's no value in leaving this question around.**

In fact, it's dangerous to leave such a highly upvoted post lying around, since people might think they can gain some quick rep asking a similar question.

As to why this should be deleted: Highly upvoted questions are still visible on the 'votes' tab. *People keep upvoting the bad stuff,* and the answers on the bad stuff. This distorts the distribution of reputation across the site. If anything, the highly upvoted stuff should go, and we can use the downvoted stuff as good examples of bad questions.

## Votes don't make value.

Valuable posts follow the community guidelines. If the guidelines change, questions and their answers can become worthless, see for example the deletion of 'identify-this-movie' requests on movies.se.

As said before here: **A good answer does not make a good question.**
*If someone can ask a better question on the same subject, we can answer that and upvote the answers to the useful post, instead of leaving crap lying around.*

> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate.

**This part of your question is not applicable here.** It is only applicable to questions that can be merged, that are exact duplicates. There's no need to look at the quality of the answers here before deciding that the question is worthless and can be deleted.

Basically, every question that

- Isn't a duplicate
- Doesn't warrant a historical lock

Is eventually up for deletion.

We need to start deleting stuff sometime, and it might be better to start with the highly upvoted stuff since it's easier to see something is bad when it's downvoted a lot.

Comment: Agreed the question was closed as too broad and not improved. Could you explain why the highly upvoted ***answers*** have no value @Tinkeringbell? (Also please explain why votes don't make value, so this can become a canonical answer for such questions.)

Comment: I don't fully understand 'potential merge candidate' but I assume it has something to do with exact duplicates. Since this question isn't a duplicate of stuff, there's absolutely no need to take the answers into account when deleting stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Tinkeringbell, though I don't understand why highly upvoted answers to an on-topic question add no value to a site because the Q got closed as too broad and not improved. Your point would be much more obvious to me if the question were ***off topic***. Also see the addition to my question: "at least 250 questions [remain closed](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?page=6&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=closed%3a1) on IPS going back to late June 2017. Are we going to delete them all? Or is there something especially delete-worthy about this particular question?"

Comment: @EnglishStudent, please.... that's about the umptieth time I wrote you an answer and you changed the question afterwards. I addressed it: We need the highly upvoted crap gone, since it is still visible to new visitors to the site... We need to start deleting stuff sometime, and it might be better to start with the highly upvoted stuff since it's easier to see something is bad when it's downvoted a lot

Comment: I only added something... My question was still being improved when you wrote your very prompt answer. *"We need to start deleting stuff sometime, and it might be better to start with the highly upvoted stuff since it's easier to see something is bad when it's downvoted a lot"* __ That makes sense. You might like to add that to your answer. Note: ***if*** we are going to delete all closed questions that were not improved, then I can accept the deletion of this Q as part of some general policy @Tinkeringbell.

Comment: @EnglishStudent probably everything that doesn't warrant a historical lock OR is a duplicate is at some point up for deletion, yes.

Comment: For sure, I only ask that the policy be applied evenly to all eligible questions. However your "start with the highly upvoted" argument is certainly convincing, thanks @Tinkeringbell. I feel that the clarifications you gave here in these comments might be edited in to improve your answer. (It will also give me the opportunity to reverse my downvote.)

Comment: @EnglishStudent Already is there?

Comment: Please permit me to edit in the part of your comment that was most convincing, @Tinkeringbell. Now reversed my initial downvote to upvote and accepted your answer.